# How to get chrome webdriver running headless?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've looked at older posts but I believe they all use code which will be deprecated. Below is the code I am using, this launches the browser but does not do so in headless mode as there is a GUI.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
s=Service(executable_path=PATH, service_args=["--disable-gpu", "--headless"])
```

Could you also kindly point me to some (updated) documentation or tutorial regarding how to use the webdriver

Answer (score 0):

This are the service args which you can pass. You can get with the following cmd
`.\chromedriver.exe -help`

```
Options
  --port=PORT                     port to listen on
  --adb-port=PORT                 adb server port
  --log-path=FILE                 write server log to file instead of stderr, increases log level to INFO
  --log-level=LEVEL               set log level: ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF
  --verbose                       log verbosely (equivalent to --log-level=ALL)
  --silent                        log nothing (equivalent to --log-level=OFF)
  --append-log                    append log file instead of rewriting
  --replayable                    (experimental) log verbosely and don't truncate long strings so that the log can be replayed.
  --version                       print the version number and exit
  --url-base                      base URL path prefix for commands, e.g. wd/url
  --readable-timestamp            add readable timestamps to log
  --enable-chrome-logs            show logs from the browser (overrides other logging options)
  --allowed-ips=LIST              comma-separated allowlist of remote IP addresses which are allowed to connect to ChromeDriver
  --allowed-origins=LIST          comma-separated allowlist of request origins which are allowed to connect to ChromeDriver. Using `*` to allow any host origin is dangerous!
```

For using headless with services you can refer [this](https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python#:%7E:text=dozens%20of%20tests.-,Manual%20vs.%20Adhoc,-In%20the%20script).

```py
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(os.path.abspath("chromedriver"))  
service.start()

chrome_options = Options()  
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.headless=True

# path to the binary of Chrome Canary that we installed earlier  
chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome   Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url,   desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

For using headless with webdriver you can do as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
```